# LibreOffice install language package from official dnf-repositories

Tags: configuration, gui, libreoffice, user-interface, language

If I check under

- tools > options > Language Settings > Languages > Language of > User interface:

it only contains "Default - English (USA)" and "English (USA)", however I would like to change to "German (Germany)" or "Deutsch (Deutschland)"

So I would like to install the german language pack of LibreOffice on Fedora (Linux).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check with `dnf list libreoffice-langpack-de` if it is installed/installable.

run: `sudo dnf install libreoffice-langpack-de`

This answer is based on [this post](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/244872/lo-language-pack-installation-failurefedora/?answer=244888#post-id-244888).