# install Libreoffice language pack on Debian

Tags: debian, libreoffice

I'm asking this as I remember trying for more than half an hour at some point in the last year and giving up, now I need to do it more urgently. Essentially to have spell-check in a European language on Libreoffice 'writer' which is not my native.

There is already an answer here to do it on Fedora -
[LibreOffice install language package from official dnf-repositories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645400/libreoffice-install-language-package-from-official-dnf-repositories)
..and several on the Ubuntu sites but I can't find any solid guide to do it on Debian.

Does anyone know how?

Not sure if it can be done through the menus or through a terminal command. I'd prefer terminal but whatever works. I'm running Debian 11 Bullseye.

Comment: which language?

Comment: At this point, was 'French' which I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Language support for LibreOffice in Debian is split across a variety of packages. The relevant ones for spell-checking are either `hunspell-dictionary-…` or `myspell-dictionary-…` packages; use `apt search hunspell-dictionary` or `apt search myspell-dictionary` to list them all. For example, [`hunspell-de-de`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/hunspell-de-de), which “provides” `hunspell-dictionary-de`, allows LibreOffice to spell-check German.

Once you’ve identified the appropriate package, install it using `sudo apt install`.